# QSQLITE driver not loaded

Tags: qt, sqlite, arm, qt4, debian

I'm creating a light APP with QT that add entries into my SQLITE base from my website.

But I've this problem :

> ("QSQLITE")
>
> QSqlError(-1, "", "")
>
> DATABASE OPENED
>
> QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open
>
> QSqlError(-1, "Driver not loaded", "Driver not loaded")

I'm on a Bananapi (Debian 7) with QT installed and upgrade from Debian-APT.

This is my code :

```
// Load QSLite driver
qDebug() << bdd.drivers(); //Said : ("QSQLITE")
bdd = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
qDebug() << bdd.lastError();

// Open the database
bdd.setDatabaseName("/var/www/config/database.sqlite");

// Connect to the database
if( ! bdd.open())
{
    qDebug() << "ERROR " << EXIT_FAILURE_CANT_OPEN_DATABASE << " : Can't open database";
    qDebug() << bdd.lastError();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE_CANT_OPEN_DATABASE);
}
else
    qDebug() << "DATABASE OPENED";

query.prepare(....); //Said : QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open.
```

Any idea ?

Comment: The `QSqlQuery` object should take the default DB connection, but just in case, try creating the object passing bdd as a parameter (`QSqlQuery query(bdd);`). That will force it to query against your database. If it does not work (or you've already tried), we can think of something else.

Comment: Yeah !!! Thank you very much :)

I've never do like that but it works, in that case : SUPER !!!

Comment: Glad to hear it! I am suspecting that you are declaring the `QSqlQuery` object before the DB is opened. If you want to do it without passing the DB connection, create the query object after the DB connection is created and it should take it as the default connection (provided that there are no other previously created DB connections). In any case, same result :)

Comment: Hum after reflexion I think it's that (I'll look at it tomorrow at work).
Thank for you explanation ;)